# как программно проверить скорость подключения к Интернету на Android

Tags: java, android

Всем привет !!!
Кто-нибудь знает, как программно проверить скорость подключения к Интернету на Android ? я хочу сообщить пользователю что-то вроде этого << Ваша скорость Интернет х Mbps >> но как получить << х >> ?

Comment: Есть такая библиотека https://github.com/akinaru/speed-test-lib может поможет

Comment: а возможно ли динамично проверять ? То есть ежесекундно узнать текущую скорость ?

Comment: @SalutAmigo возможно узнать текущую скорость скачки. Посмотрите, например, 2ip.ru - там при проверке скорости интернета проходит не одна секунда, более того, на время проверки просят закрыть другие вкладки и подключения.

Answer (score 2):

Для этого Вам требуется её измерить. Подход такой:

1. Получаете метку времени начала скачивания.
2. Скачиваете с сервера файл известного размера.
3. Получаете метку времени завершения скачивания.
4. Сравниваете и высчитываете, исходя из размера файла.

   Тем самым Вы получите скорость входящего канала. Потом этот же файл возвращаете на сервер и высчитываете скорость исходящего канала.

Comment: а возможно ли динамично проверять ? То есть ежесекундно узнать текущую скорость ?

Comment: Можно узнать текущую загруженность канала. Или узнавать скорость на которой установлено соединение со шлюзом. Но к реальной доступной скорости интернета это будет иметь отношение чуть более, чем никакое.

Answer (score 0):

У Facebook есть замечательная библиотека [Network Connection Class](https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class), которая поможет вам осуществить задуманное.

Comment: а возможно ли динамично проверять ? То есть ежесекундно узнать текущую скорость ?